# Initializing a multi-dimensional array in C++ 20 using an expression list

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, initialization, declaration, c++20

Is it correct such an initialization of a multi-dimensional array in C++ 20 using an expression list?

```
int a[][3]( 1, 2, 3, { 4, 5, 6 } );
```

At least the C++ compiler of MS VS 2019 does not compile such a declaration

This declaration

```
int a[][3]( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 );
```

is not also compiled while this declaration

```
int a[][3]( { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 } );
```

is compiled successfuly.

In the corresponding quote from the C++ 20 Standard (9.4 Initializers) relative to array initialization there is nothing said about whether brace elision is allowed or not when an expression list is used.

> (17.5) — Otherwise, if the destination type is an array, the object is
> initialized as follows. Let x1, . . . , xk be the elements of the
> expression-list. If the destination type is an array of unknown bound,
> it is defined as having k elements. Let n denote the array size after
> this potential adjustment. If k is greater than n, the program is
> ill-formed. Otherwise, the ith array element is copy-initialized with
> xi for each 1 ≤ i ≤ k, and value-initialized for each k < i ≤ n. For
> each 1 ≤ i < j ≤ n, every value computation and side effect associated
> with the initialization of the ith element of the array is sequenced
> before those associated with the initialization of the jth element.

Comment: Looks a bit suspect.  Do you have the pedantic flag enabled (whatever that is for **CL.EXE**)?  `language-lawyer` tag?

Comment: Rejected by clang, gcc and msvc - live - https://godbolt.org/z/EzE37dr6j  Can you post a link to _"expression list"_ hard to pin down.

Comment: The way to go is: int a[][3]{ {2}, {3}, { 4, 5, 6 }}; (guessing you expect the first dimension to be 4).

Comment: @phe Pay attention to that I am speaking about an expression list that is your example should look like  int a[][3]( {2}, {3}, { 4, 5, 6 }); (outer parentheses instead of braces)

Comment: @phe With braces (list initialization) this declaration int a[][3]{ 1, 2, 3, { 4, 5, 6 } }; is valid. There is no problem

Comment: I was referring to "If the initializer clause is a nested braced-init-list (which is not an expression), the corresponding array element/class member/public base (since C++17) is list-initialized from that clause: aggregate initialization is recursive."  [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rereading the provided quote especially its this part

> the ith array element is copy-initialized with xi for each 1 ≤ i ≤ k

It seems that such an initialization like this

```
int a[][3]( 1, 2, 3, { 4, 5, 6 } );
```

is indeed incorrect because the element of the array `a` is in turn an array of the type `int[3]` and to initialize it in this case you need to use a braced-init-list. After that within the braced-init-list the brace elision will be accepted. That is you may not initialize an array with an expression.

Here is an example that confirms that and is compiled by the C++ compiler of MS VS 2019

```
int e[][2][3]( { 1, 2, 3,  { 4, 5, 6 } }, { 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 } );
```

Within the braced-init-lists the brace elision may be used.

Answer (score -1):

Taken from [c++ 20 draft](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/N4860.pdf)

```
7.6.1
expression-list:
  initializer-list

9.4
initializer-clause :
   assignment-expression
   braced-init-list

initializer-list:
   initializer-clause ...opt
   initializer-list , initializer-clause ...opt
```

`a[][2]({1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6})` is ok

`a[][2](1, 2, 3, {4, 5, 6})` is not ok because 1, 2, 3, {4, 5, 6} is not an expression-list

That mean the () syntax for array is pointless, anyway the inner part need to be a {} except for:

`int e[](1);`

because 1 is an assignment-expression